# ChatScript - is it possible to integrate with python?

Tags: python, chatscript

I'm new in the programming world. I try to make a conversational chatbot for Discord. On the basic level it is finished, it uses simple AIML files with "questions and replies" templates. I found it is very primitive tool, as my native language is highly inflective and words in a sentence can be in very different order while keeping the same meaning of the sentence. I would have to write a lot of rules in AIML.

I found a very similar, but much more powerful tool - ChatScript, where some of my problems have already been resolved (word order for example).

Is it possible to integrate ChatScript with Python?
Has anyone used chatscript for a language other than English?

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/candlewill/ChatScript_Client ?

Comment: I will check it, thanks!